# repeat a function n times in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to repeat a function n times on a table, For n=2 I have the following code, How can I be sure that the function had run twice since my fc is differend every time?

```
smat = Table[{9, 8, 10}, {3}]

f[x_?Table] :=  ReplacePart[
 x, {{2, 1} -> x[[2]][[1]] - #, {2, 2} -> x[[2]][[2]] + #}] &@ fc[x[[2]][[1]]];

fc[k_?NumericQ] := Count[RandomReal[{0, 1}, k], x_ /; x < .1]

Nest[f, smat, 2]
```

Comment: The way I read this, your only changing two vectors: `x[[2]][[1]]` and `x[[2]][[2]]` in your 3D array. Is this your intent?

Comment: @rcollyer yes this is what I want. My question is how can I be sure that my code works since the fc is random (different every time according to random numbers) amd I may have the same result by running my function n times with 1 time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Acl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590147/repeat-a-function-n-times-in-mathematica/6590193#6590193) covered the problems with the code pretty well, so I won't. To answer your question, though, I'd first separate your functions `f` and `fc` in separate cells, with `fc` being declared prior to `f`, and preface each cell with `Clear[<function name>]`.  Now, to test if `f` is being applied twice, temporarily replace `fc` with

```
fc[_]:= a
```

or use another "dummy" value other than a, but it should be symbolic to increase readability.  As a point of note, `{1,2,3} + a == {1 + a, 2 + a, 3 + a}`, so if `f` is applied twice, each term in `x[[2]][[1]]` and `x[[2]][[2]]` will have `2 a` added to it.

Now, if you are unsure if `fc` is working correctly by itself, I'd apply it to a number separate cases without `f`, first.

Comment: @Noni, simple divide and conquer. The cell structure allows for this like few other platforms. Also, note the purpose of `Clear` is to provide you with a method to reset the definitions as you experiment.

Comment: You could also Sow something every time, then Reap and see how many were sown. Less disruptive.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you want:

```
smat = Table[{9, 8, 10}, {3}]
ClearAll[f, fc];

f[x_List] := 
 ReplacePart[
 x, {{2, 1} -> x[[2]][[1]] - #, {2, 2} -> x[[2]][[2]] + #}] &@
 fc[x[[2]][[1]]];

 fc[k_?NumericQ] := Count[RandomReal[{0, 1}, k], x_ /; x < .1]

Nest[f, smat, 2]
```

`ClearAll` clears any previous definitions for those symbols (just in case). `f[x_?Table]` won't work; you want `f[x_List]`, which means that the argument has a `List` head (`Table` is not a `Head`, and `?` isn't what you want here).

I am not sure I have really answered your question though...

EDIT: To be clear, `f[x_?something]` means "apply `something` to `x` and, if it returns `True`, evaluate the right hand side of the `:=` that follows. Look up `PatternTest` in Mathematica's documentation for more.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for. I don't know why but it does not let me to accept it as the answer I was looking for. I will try again later. Thanks again

Comment: @noni wait a bit more, maybe someone will give a better one!